# Synchronize Sharepoint List with multiple Excel files

Tags: 2010, list, excel

I have a list on SharePoint,and I would like to update that list from any excel sheet/file I create "Having same formatting of course". Can I achieve that?

I know that you can create a List on SharePoint from an excel sheet "Table Format" but I couldn't find any solution to sync SharePoint list from any excel sheet.
Shall I do some scripting to achieve that ?

I'm using Excel 2010 and SharePoint 2010

Comment: What version of SharePoint are you using and what version of office?

Comment: @garvon-77 it is mentioned at the end :) 
2010 for both

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this out of the box. I suggest having a look at [SharePoint List Synchronizer](http://www.synchronizer-for-excel-and-sharepoint.com) (disclaimer: I work for SoftFluent, the company behind this tool).

On top of what Microsoft tool offers, it lets you start from SharePoint. So you can read and modify your existing SharePoint lists from Excel. Any version of Excel, any version of SharePoint. Most formatting is kept.